# Test failing for uploading documents fails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to test for uploading documents in rails. I am using carrierwave to upload documents. The relevant code is given below.

**Document Model Test Code**

```
class DocumentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup 
    @category = categories(:category_a)
    @document = @category.documents.build(file_name: "abc", file: "abc.doc")
  end

  test "document valid" do 
    assert @document.valid?
  end
```

**Document Model Code**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

  validates :file_name, presence: true
  validates :file, presence: true
  validate  :file_size
end
```

**file_uploader code**

The following are the files I have whitelisted.

```
  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf doc htm html docx xlsx xml)
  end
```

I get a `Failed assertion` when I run the tests. I commented out the `validates :file, presence: true` code and the tests pass. I have file as type `string` in the database. However, passing in a string value is the same as passing a blank value. Therefore, the `presence: true` validation fails. I am not sure why that is failing even though I am passing in a string value. I think I need to pass in additional params or information for the tests to know what kind of file it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you pass a file to the carrierwave model. Have a look at these examples: 
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-test-factories

Also, carrierwave has its own validators you might want to use:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Validate-uploads-with-Active-Record